# Angular 8: await till son component is created

Tags: angular, viewchildren

I have a 'father' component which has few 'son-s' components.
The 'father' creates 'sons' by the following code:

```js
export class FatherComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren(SonComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) sonComponent: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>
    sonTitle: string;
    items: number[];

    public CreateChildren(val: any) {
        let NofChildren = val;
        this.items = new Array(NofChildren);

        //Wait till number of sons=2
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p-tabView [styleClass]="'main'">
        <p-tabPanel [header]='sonTitle+(i+1)' *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [selected]="i == 0">
            <app-page #sonComponent ></app-page>
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
</div>
```

Can you please explain:
How should I "wait" till all 'sons' are created ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() 
Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When ngAfterViewInit runs, it can see 2 'sons'. I want to wait int CreateChildren till those 'sons' are created.